# MySQL change column default to not null

Tags: mysql

```
ALTER TABLE `pages` MODIFY `views` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

Trying to alter a column in a table which is currently allows NULL and has no default.

I want it to be `NOT NULL` and have a default of `0`.

The Error message I get is

> Invalid use of NULL value

Comment: The SQL works on my device.

Comment: Do you have data in table pages already?  if so you may need to `update pages set views to be 0 where views is null` 1st then run your alter.  Pretty sure default 0 applies to new rows, not existing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is because the table already has a row or more with null value, you might need to update those to 0 before executing `ALTER` table, e.g.:

```
UPDATE test SET views = 0 WHERE views IS NULL;
ALTER TABLE test MODIFY COLUMN views int NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2be00e/2/0)** (commenting out `update` statement will result in the same error).